# When I open my flutter app it always shows SignIn screen for few seconds, even if I already signed In in my last session. And after that Main page

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-signin

When I start my flutter app, it starts with sign in screen even if I already logged in. And automatically after few seconds it open the main page.

My code:
My main build:-

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

//saveUserInfoToFireStore();
if(isSignedIn)
{
  return buildHomeScreen();
}
else{
  return buildSignInScreen();
}
}
```

This is my init function:-

```
bool isSignedIn = false;
void initState() {
super.initState();

pageController = PageController();

gSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((gSigninAccount){
  controlSignIn(gSigninAccount);
}, onError:(gError){
  print("Error Message: " +gError);
});

gSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((gSignInAccount){
  controlSignIn(gSignInAccount);

}).catchError((gError){
  print("Error Message: "+gError); // + gerror
});
}

controlSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) async {
if(signInAccount != null)
  {

     final GoogleSignInAccount gCurrentUser = gSignIn.currentUser;
     DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await usersReference.doc(gCurrentUser.id).get();
     currentUser = User.fromDocument(documentSnapshot);
     setState(() {
       isSignedIn=true;
     });


    configureRealTimePushNotifications();
  }
else{
  setState(() {
    isSignedIn = false;
  });
}
}
```

once I signed In I want that every time I open my app it should only shows homepage, rather that SignIn page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `controlSignIn` method to determine whether the user is logged in or not. As it is an `async` function, it is taking some time to determine the signed-in user. Hence you are able to see the sign-in page for a second, then the home page.

You can fix this by checking this logic in the splash screen & then navigating to the appropriate page - sign in or home.

Create a new file: `splash_page.dart`. Your `SplashPage` should look something like this:

```
class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashPageState createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // your logic to check whether user is signed in or not
    // If user is logged in navigate to HomePage widget
    // Else navigate to SignInPage
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
}
```

Comment: How to check this logic in splash screen? can you please give a idea.